# Voronoi diagram polygons enclosed in geographic borders

Tags: r, maps, polygons, voronoi, spatstat

I am trying to create Voronoi polygons (aka Dirichlet tessellations or Thiessen polygons) within a fixed geographic region for a set of points. However, I am having trouble finding a method in R that will bound the polygons within the map borders. My main goal is to get accurate area calculations (not simply to produce a visual plot). For example, the following visually communicates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
library(maps)
library(deldir)
data(countyMapEnv)
counties <- map('county', c('maryland,carroll','maryland,frederick', 'maryland,montgomery', 'maryland,howard'), interior=FALSE)
x <- c(-77.208703, -77.456582, -77.090600,  -77.035668, -77.197144)
y <- c(39.188603, 39.347019, 39.672818, 39.501898, 39.389203)
points(x,y)
vt <- deldir(x, y, rw=counties$range)
plot(vt, wlines="tess", lty="solid", add=TRUE)
```

which produces the following:

[image: Voronoi polygons for the 5 locations]

Conceptually I want to intersect `counties` with `vt` which should provide a set of polygons bounded by the county borders and accurate area calculations for each. Right now, `vt$summary` provides area calculations for each polygon, but they are obviously overstated for all but the one interior polygon, and `deldir()` appears to only accept rectangular enclosings for its `rw` argument. I am new to R's geospacial capabilities, so am open to other approaches beyond what I outlined above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use the `spatstat` function `dirichlet` for this.

The first task is to get the counties converted into a spatstat observation window of class `owin` (code partially based on the answer by @jbaums):

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(spatstat)
library(rgeos)

counties <- map('county', c('maryland,carroll', 'maryland,frederick', 
                            'maryland,montgomery', 'maryland,howard'), 
                fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
# fill=TRUE is necessary for converting this map object to SpatialPolygons
countries <- gUnaryUnion(map2SpatialPolygons(counties, IDs=counties$names,
                                 proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))
W <- as(countries, "owin")
```

Then you just put the five points in the `ppp` format, make the Dirichlet tesslation and calctulate the areas:

```
X <- ppp(x=c(-77.208703, -77.456582, -77.090600,  -77.035668, -77.197144),
         y=c(39.188603, 39.347019, 39.672818, 39.501898, 39.389203), window = W)

y <- dirichlet(X) # Dirichlet tesselation
plot(y) # Plot tesselation
plot(X, add = TRUE) # Add points
tile.areas(y) #Areas
```

Comment: (+1) Ha, very nice indeed - a lot less stuffing around. Feel free to add the info about converting the `map` to a `SpatialPolygon` from my answer.

Comment: I guess so, but at the same time the answer is missing the correct polygons, but I hope it sufficient for @Bryan.

Comment: OK. I will try to include the info about converting the map to a SpatialPolygon from @jbaums answer.

Comment: @EgeRubak and @jbaums, this is great, thanks so much. I had tried the `spatstat` approach but I was missing the conversion of the map to the `owin` class, so these are both super helpful. However, any idea why the first tile of the tessellation has two sets of `bdry` (i.e., `y$tiles[[1]]$bdry` lists one tiny polygon in upper left corner in addition to the main one)? I noticed this when I was attempting to loop through each tile to do area overlap calculations with a different set of polygons.

Comment: Also, I edited the above to include @jbaums' `gUnaryUnion` usage, as I was getting weird county lines when plotting another set of data.

Comment: I moved the gUnaryUnion command to the correct line (hopefully). I can't reproduce the strange y$tiles[[1]]$bdry behaviour you are talking about. Does it happen with the code above, and what is your spatstat version?

Comment: I'm using spatstat 1.37-0. However, the y$tiles[[1]]$bdry issue seems to be solved by using `gUnaryUnion`. If you run it without gUnaryUnion you'll see the extra polygon in that first tile.

Answer (score 10):

Once we have both the Voronoi polygons and the `counties` as `SpatialPolygons` objects, we can achieve this with the help of `gIntersection`.

First, let's load some necessary libraries and prepare your data.

```
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)

counties <- map('county', c('maryland,carroll', 'maryland,frederick', 
                            'maryland,montgomery', 'maryland,howard'), 
                fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
# fill=TRUE is necessary for converting this map object to SpatialPolygons

p <- data.frame(x=c(-77.208703, -77.456582, -77.090600,  -77.035668, -77.197144),
                y=c(39.188603, 39.347019, 39.672818, 39.501898, 39.389203))
```

Now we can convert our `counties` `map` object to `SpatialPolygons` with `map2SpatialPolygons` from the `maptools` package. I've wrapped it in `rgeos::gUnaryUnion` to combine the four polygons into a single polygon (otherwise we'd have internal boundaries plotted down the track). I've also added the relevant projection.

```
counties.sp <- gUnaryUnion(
  map2SpatialPolygons(counties, IDs=counties$names,
                      proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")))
```

For converting the `deldir` object to a `SpatialPolygons` object, there's a nice function that I referred to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9405831/489704) (hat-tip to [Carson Farmer](http://carsonfarmer.com/2009/09/voronoi-polygons-with-r/)) and which @Spacedman subsequently modified (to clip to a given extent) and posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12159863/489704).

```
voronoipolygons <- function(x, poly) {
  require(deldir)
  if (.hasSlot(x, 'coords')) {
    crds <- x@coords  
  } else crds <- x
  bb = bbox(poly)
  rw = as.numeric(t(bbox(poly)))
  z <- deldir(crds[,1], crds[,2],rw=rw)
  w <- tile.list(z)
  polys <- vector(mode='list', length=length(w))
  require(sp)
  for (i in seq(along=polys)) {
    pcrds <- cbind(w[[i]]$x, w[[i]]$y)
    pcrds <- rbind(pcrds, pcrds[1,])
    polys[[i]] <- Polygons(list(Polygon(pcrds)), ID=as.character(i))
  }
  SP <- SpatialPolygons(polys)

  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
    SP, data.frame(x=crds[,1], y=crds[,2], 
                   row.names=sapply(slot(SP, 'polygons'), 
                                    function(x) slot(x, 'ID'))))  
}
```

Now we can go ahead and use this to create our Voronoi `SpatialPolygons`.

```
v <- voronoipolygons(p, counties.sp)
proj4string(v) <- proj4string(counties.sp)
```

All that's left to do now is intersect the two geometries - the bread and butter of `rgeos`:

```
final <- gIntersection(counties.sp, v, byid=TRUE)

plot(final)
points(p, pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: How do I fill colors to each tile of the merged map? The `deldir` package takes method `plot.tile.list` but it fills colors over the whole square.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed!